# NDSolve error (not a real number when the arguments are?)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, complex

For the NDSolve, I have problem. It seems to be non-zero imaginary part of the number.
How can I get over this issue?
The following is the script.

```
a = 5;
b = 10;
c = 200;
d = 1675000;
Array[f, c];
Array[g, {a, b}];
Array[g2, b];
k = 1; While[k <= b, Do[g[t, k] = 0, {t, a}]; k++];
k = 1; While[k <= b, g2[k] = 0; k++];

G = 2.68;

Z = 2.9;

n = 1; While[n <= c, f[n] = NDSolve[{y''[x] == 1.2*Cos[(y[x]) + Arg[Exp[3*I*x]]], 
y'[0] == 2.606, y[0] == (n - 1)/c*2*Pi - Pi}, y, {x, 0, 1}]; n++];

NDSolve::nrnum1: The function value 1. +0.000275068 I is not a real      number when the arguments are {0.0000916894,1}. >>

NDSolve::nrnum1: The function value 1. +0.000275068 I is not a real number when the arguments are {0.0000916894,1}. >>

NDSolve::nrnum1: The function value 1. +0.000550136 I is not a real number when the arguments are {0.000183379,1}. >>

General::stop: Further output of NDSolve::nrnum1 will be suppressed during this calculation. `
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Arg` is discontinuous and your ODE explicitly contains an imaginary `I`.  The `Arg` invokes discontinuity processing, which constructs an event function.  The `I` probably causes the use of complex numbers internally, even though they are unnecessary.  The event functions usually detect events as zero crossings.  Zero crossings are not well-defined if the numbers used are complex.  I suspect that is the source of the error.

Try using `ArcTan[Cos[3x], Sin[3x]]` instead of `Arg[Exp[3*I*x]]`.  The errors go away.

Comment: Plausible. An evidence is, if one set `Method -> "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False` in `NDSolve`, the warning goes away, too. The result is the same as using `ComplexExpand@Arg[Exp[3*I*x]]`.